# Gps tracker received data,

Tags: gps, hex, latitude-longitude

in advance I want to appreciate any answer and suggestion on this problem,

I am am working on a GPS tracker module (Model: m528), It's poorly documented so I dont have any paper on the data format which it sends,

I have my own server that listens to a special port and gets the data packets sent by the module,

I know the position of the latitude and longitude in the received packets, each of them have 4 bytes without N, W, S, E indicators,

this are the examples which I think would help,

stored latitude data in hex: 03447535
latitude value: 34.79225

stored longitude data in hex: 04830690
longitude value: 48.51150

any help and suggestion would be appreciated,
thanks every one

Comment: Where do you need help?  I am guessing:Converting decimal to lat/long? 03447535 hex is 54818101 in base 10. How did you get 34.79...?  Are you using state plane coordinates?

Comment: hi mojtaba, how are you setting the module to send the data to your server? can you give me some references as to understand how to program gps trackers?

Comment: hi, I send an sms to the module to set the server , but i cant exacly remember what was the sms content. There is no reference on this modules and I just reverse engineered the module.

Comment: hi, can you help me to find the data from the hex data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's easy to convert, first you separate 3 decimal places, that would be degrees:

```
03447535 -> 034 degrees
```

then you take the rest and divide by 60000:

```
47535 / 60000 = 0.79225
```

finally you add 34 degrees and the result:

```
34.79225
```

same with the other number:

```
04830690 -> 48 degrees + 30690 / 60000 = 48.5115
```

Answer (score 5):

What you have there doesn't seem to be any hex representation. It seems to be degrees/minutes: 03447535 = 34°47.535' = 34.79225 decimal...