# GPS data location conversion

Tags: gps, hex, latitude-longitude

Thanks in advance I want to appreciate any answer and suggestion on this problem.

I am am working on a GPS tracker module (Model: topflytech), It's not properly documented so I don't have any paper on the data format which it sends,

I have my own server that listens to a special port and gets the data packets sent by the module,

I know the position of the latitude and longitude in the received packets, each of them have 4 bytes without N, W, S, E indicators,

this are the examples which I think would help,

stored latitude data in hex: 0x91 0x2A 0XB4 0X41  and it is parsed latitude value: 22.52078

stored longitude data in hex: 0x76 0xD6 0XE3 0X42  and it is parsed longitude value: 113.9189

any help and suggestion would be appreciated, thanks every one

Comment: What it is the question? How to get from such binary to latitude?

Comment: yes..I want to convert from hex to given latitude,longitude

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355604/how-to-convert-gps-longitude-and-latitude-from-hex and

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543321/gps-tracker-received-data